# Macro that swallows semicolon outside of function

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

Is there any idiom that forces a semicolon after a cpp macro outside of a function?

The known solution for macros used inside functions is:

```
#define MACRO(x) \
  do {
    x * 2;
  } while(0)
```

However, say I have a macro that looks like the following:

```
#define DETAIL(warning) _Pragma(#warning)
#define WARNING_DISABLE(warning) DETAIL(GCC diagnostic ignore warning)
```

What can I put in the macro that would force a semi-colon after that statement.  The statement could be used in or outside of a function:

```
WARNING_DISABLE("-Wunused-local-typedefs")
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
void foo(const int x) {
    WARNING_DISABLE("-Wsome-warning")
    ...
}
```

Is there any C/C++ syntax that will force a semi-colon in the parser at any point in a file that doesn't have side effects?

**Edit:** A possible use case:

```
#define MY_CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(test_suite_class) \
  WARNING_PUSH \
  /* the declaration of the copy assignment operator has been suppressed */ \
  INTEL_WARNING_DISABLE(2268) \
  /* the declaration of the copy assignment operator has been suppressed */ \
  INTEL_WARNING_DISABLE(2270) \
  /* the declaration of the copy constructor operator has been suppressed */ \
  INTEL_WARNING_DISABLE(2273) \
  CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(test_suite_class); \
  WARNING_POP \
  /* force a semi-colon */ \
  UDP_KEYSTONE_DLL_LOCAL struct __udp_keystone_cppunit_test_suite ## __LINE__ {}
```

Comment: The *other* example I would like to use this for is specifying the code sections when compiling for embedded, which are a pragma so it would be great if it was `CODE_SECTION(...);` instead of `CODE_SECTION(...)`.  Obviously it isn't the end of the world but wondering if anyone has the preprocessor-fu to accomplish this?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is putting `_Pragma(#x); typedef int __dummy_ ## __LINE__` but that ends up with loads of warnings about unused typedefs on gcc 4.8.1

Comment: Warnings can be disabled, as you well know ;)

Comment: Your problem is not the semicolon, is any character after the current position in the same line, and I don't think that general problem can be solved. Admitting that the general problem cannot be solved, just leave it as is and document it with the macro: no extra characters must be present in the line.

Comment: @SvenS :) I know, just would be nice if there was something that didn't have warnings

Comment: Why do you want to force the use of a semicolon? A macro invocation isn't a C/C++ statement, and I can't see any point in trying to disguise it as one.

Comment: @MikeSeymour No reason other than I wondered if it could be done.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Added a possible use case to the question, the `CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE` macro requires a semi colon but I need to wrap it with warning disables.  The warning disables don't require the semi-colon so the `MY_CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE` doesn't work like the original macro, however, if I force the semi colon on the end it does.  Best I can do for a use case! Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#define DETAIL(warning) _Pragma(#warning) struct X ## __LINE__ {}
```

Comment: Do you think the compiler would generally optimise out the `X[LINE]` symbol from the library?  Works without errors, better than my `typedef` idea. `+1` from me :)

Comment: @MattClarkson I don't know enough about object file contents to answer that, sorry.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need **LINE** trick - it is enough to forward-declare some structure, which is allowed multiple times and there is no need for actual definition. Also collision with actual struct should not be a problem.

```
#define DETAIL(warning) _Pragma(#warning) struct dummy
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest is an extern function declaration

```
#define MACRO_END_(LINE) extern void some_inprobable_long_function_name ## LINE(void)
#define MACRO_END MACRO_END_(__LINE__)
```

the line trick is only there because some compilers with excessive warnings give you warnings on duplicate declarations.

This macro works in any context where a declaration is allowed, so with C99 almost everywhere:

```
#define DETAIL(warning) _Pragma(#warning) MACRO_END
```